# subquery from SELECT reference, gets me a "cannot be referenced from this part of the query"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm dealing with this [question](https://pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/nbooking.html)
I know the simple aggregate answer, but I figured out to try to challenge myself with subqueries.

```
SELECT outercm.surname, outercm.firstname, outercm.memid, subq.starttime
FROM cd.members outercm,
(
SELECT cm.memid, cb.starttime
from cd.members cm
JOIN cd.bookings cb ON cb.memid = cm.memid
WHERE cm.memid = outercm.memid
AND
DATE(starttime ) >= '01-09-2012'
ORDER BY cb.starttime
LIMIT 1
  ) as subq
```

And I get this error:

> There is an entry for table "outercm", but it cannot be referenced
>   from this part of the query.

I've also tried subqueries from the FROM:

```
SELECT outercm.surname, outercm.firstname, outercm.memid, 
(
  SELECT cb.starttime
  from cd.members cm
  JOIN cd.bookings cb ON cb.memid = cm.memid
  WHERE cm.memid = outercm.memid
  AND
  DATE(starttime ) >= '01-09-2012'
  ORDER BY cb.starttime
  LIMIT 1 
) 
FROM cd.members outercm
```

And i get this message:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

I'm not sure, when and how can i reference betweein inner and outer queries.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Is your first query the complete query? Can you share the full SQL if not where the alias `outercm` is declared? I suspect that your `String index out of range` is due to your rando date format. Instead use `'2012-01-09'::date` for your date literal. That second query may run then as it looks okay to me.

Comment: @JNevill Sorry, didn't noticed this part was gone.
Edited.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, `DISTINCT ON` can be used to get results for highest/lowest row per group, in your example the "first booking". This is generally far efficient when compared to other options like `GROUP BY` + `MIN()` or using `LIMIT` in a correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( cm.memid ) cm.surname, 
   --get the first among memid  
                                cm.firstname, 
                                cm.memid, 
                                cb.starttime 
FROM   cd.members cm 
       join cd.bookings cb 
         ON cb.memid = cm.memid 
            AND cb.starttime >= TIMESTAMP '2012-09-01' 
ORDER  BY cm.memid,     --for each memid 
          cb.starttime; --that has the earliest date
```